# What's the name of this plant?

Tags: identification, tropical

[image][image][image]

Hi,

Can you help me finding the name of this plant? I made some research but I couldn't find anything.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

snow bush  Snowbush

Breynia distichia

Snowbush is a soft pink fantasy of a shrub with an airy, delicate look - a South Florida favorite for its romantic, informal appeal.

Answer (score 1):

Could be a form of "Ficus benjamina"? perhaps a variegated one.. If it has fairly tough leaves?.look on Wikipedia.hope it helps.
Actually it also could be a Symphoricarpos although it would take me ages to try to identify exactly which one- but only if the leaves are quite soft? or if it has berries at some point(poisonous- doesn't mean its still quite a nice plant)...again another one for Wikipedia- nice photos on there of both. hope it helps